Mouse moving by itself
My mouse keeps moving and clicking by itself. It stops when I have a second screen attached and use an auxiliary mouse, but if it's just the aux mouse and no second screen it will jump around and sometimes disappear if I'm in my work vdi.
I have already disabled my touch pad while using aux mouse but still having the same issue.
How do I fix this?
Details below:

Os: Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS 64 bit
Gnome version: 3.36.8
Computer: Dell XPS-13-9310 dev edition


Welcome to AskUbuntu. I have been solving it rebooting the laptop.

I had something similar and it turned out to be a semi-broken wire as it goes into the mouse. Try a different mouse. (Fixed mine by shortening the wire and reconnecting the wire but I am an Electronics Engineer.)

This happens even if my aux mouse is not connected. It happens more actually if it isn't connected, I have been able to stop it shortly after reboot but still happens again and it's getting worse. Since I use this is my main laptop I use it for work and study but it's been really messing me up.

It sounds like a few things could be causing your mouse issues:
Touchpad or Device Conflicts: Even though you've disabled your touchpad, there might still be some interference. Try using xinput to fully disable it.
Graphics or Display Problems: Since it stops when you add a second screen, your graphics drivers might need updating. Also, double-check your display settings.
Calibration: The mouse or touchpad might need recalibration. You can adjust their sensitivity in the settings.
Background Software: Check if any programs are using up too many resources by running htop or top, and see if there's a VDI setting causing the issue.
Try a Different Desktop Environment: Switching to something like XFCE or KDE could help if GNOME is the culprit.
Hardware Issues: If none of the above works, it might be a hardware problem with the mouse or touchpad itself.

I think it was a hardware issue. I dropped my laptop a few days ago and all the mouse issues have stopped ...
